# settings.py not retrieving Django-Environ info server side

Tags: python, django, postgresql

### my Issue

Hello, I am having issues with my website fetching the information from my Django-envrion file to settings.py. I am able to open up `localhost:8000` on my dev computer perfectly with the same configuration (just Debug set to off and using the local DB). Although when I boot up my server I have issues logging into postgres, Also debug is set to on despite the environment file being set to `0`. There are also some oddities where it might fetch the Database name and Database user as those are in the environment files.

Here is the error that shows up (despite debug is off like i mentioned prior although it can read some attributes I believe considiering it knows what database and the name for the user):

```py
OperationalError at /

connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "DBuser"
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "DBuser"

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    https://[REDACTED].com/
Django Version:     4.2.3
Exception Type:     OperationalError
Exception Value:    

connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "DBuser"
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "DBuser"

Exception Location:     /home/[REDACTED]/virtenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py, line 122, in connect
Raised during:  jobs.views.home
Python Executable:  /home/[REDACTED]/virtenv/bin/python
Python Version:     3.10.12
Python Path:    

['/home/[REDACTED]/WebPortfolio/portfolio_Proj',
 '/home/[REDACTED]/virtenv/bin',
 '/usr/lib/python310.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10',
 '/usr/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
 '/home/[REDACTED]/virtenv/lib/python3.10/site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 19 Oct 2023 01:02:58 +0000
Error during template rendering

In template /home/[REDACTED]/WebPortfolio/portfolio_Proj/jobs/templates/jobs/home.html, error at line 6
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "DBuser" connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "DBuser"
```

### My Attempt

So how I tried to resolve my issue was trying to see if my python environment matched my development environment, which it does.

```py
Package           Version
----------------- -------
asgiref           3.7.2
Django            4.2.3
django-environ    0.11.2
gunicorn          21.2.0
packaging         23.1
Pillow            10.0.0
pip               23.2.1
psycopg2-binary   2.9.6
setuptools        68.0.0
sqlparse          0.4.4
typing_extensions 4.7.1
wheel             0.40.0
```

Next I tried just hard coding the information in the django-env file into the settings. That worked so I reverted the changes and checked if my imports and django-env path is correct. Here is a snippit of my `settings.py`:

```py
import environ
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Django Enviroment file path
env = environ.Env()
env.read_env(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '.djenv/', '.host'))

SECRET_KEY = env("KEY")
DEBUG = env("DEBUG")
...
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':env('DB_ENGINE'),
        'NAME':env('DB_NAME'),
        'USER':env('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD':env('DB_PASS'),
        'HOST':env('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT':env('DB_PORT'),
    }
}
```

and here is my django-env file `[proj_base_dir]/.djenv/.host`:

```py
DEBUG=0
KEY=[REDACTED]
DB_ENGINE=django.db.backends.postgresql
DB_NAME=[REDACTED]
DB_USER=[REDACTED]
DB_PASS=[REDACTED]
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=5432
```

I feel like I am missing something but i don't have a strong grasp at Django. does anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using Django-Environ make sure that you are aware of comment characters such as `#`. If your username, password, or any other thing you are trying to call from a Django environment file make sure you don't use `#` since it will comment out everything after it. alternatively if you **Must** use a `#` use quotes around it.

Here is an example:

```
DEBUG=1
SECRETPASS='agr!#eJ6CysoL*'
```